# emberjs where should document ready functions go?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to attach a [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) to a text input in one of my templates. Because Ember use's handlebars, jQuery's document ready function is not the place for the typeahead definition. Where is the proper place to put "template ready" code? I tried a controller but there was no response from the typeahead. I don't think the template was rendered yet.

```
App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    isEditing: false,

    init: function(){
        this._super();

        $('.example-films .typeaheadcx').typeahead([{
              name: 'best-picture-winners',
              remote: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
              prefetch: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/post_1960.json',
              template: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> â€“ {{year}}</p>',
              engine: Ember.Handlebars
        }]);
    },

    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },

        doneEditing: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct place is `didInsertElement` of `Ember.View`.

For example:

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
  Hello world
</script>
```

**View**

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'foo',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log(this.$().text()); // will log 'hello world'
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks...this seems like the correct answer but what if i'm trying to do this in a partial? my template name is "show/_edit". Seems to break the routing. https://bitbucket.org/dadamssg/embercrm/src

Comment: Sorry but, I cannot see the `show/_edit` in your repository. Partials are very simple, isn't possible to create a view to a partial. If a understand your problem you will use the typehead for some input in your form. My suggestion is to create some ember component or Ember.TextField subclass and in the didInsertElement use the typehead. So in that custom view you will pass the values using binding, like {{App.TypeHead valueBinding="category" ...}}. And you will have the advantage of use it in any template :)

Comment: sweet. I went ahead and created a View for the typeahead. it's working nicely. thanks for the help!